# Этимология слова "блат", "блатной"

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы узнать, откуда в русском языке появилось слово "блат" и производное от него "блатной"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блат - (по Фасмеру - от идиш blat — «посвященный, согласный»; или польск. (воровск.) blat - «взятка», в свою очередь от нем. die Blatt - «бумажн. деньги»[1]) — жаргонное слово, широко распространённое на территории бывшего СССР, означающее знакомство или связи, используемые в личных целях и ущемляющие интересы третьих лиц.

Нынешнее значение слова «блат» — полезные связи, знакомства, благодаря которым можно получить какие-то блага в обход общепринятых правил и законов, как правило, в ущерб интересам общества или государства. «По блату» — благодаря выгодному знакомству, через «нужных» людей.

(Вики)

Comment: В прежние времена слово "блатной" четко ассоциировалось с криминальной, тюремной средой. Хотя слово "блат" имело современный смысл. Помню, что для меня было удивлением услышать "блатной" = прилагательное от "блат" в фильме "Гараж". Может, конечно, это мой личный опыт: все-таки в те времена сленг и жаргон были более локализованы и в разных городах/слоях общества могли восприниматься по-разному.